# Pronunciation of "hypokeimenon"

Tags: pronunciation

How should *hypokeimenon* be pronounced?

---

P.S. For the curious, a sci-fi book I'm reading used several words I did not know. When I looked them up, I also ran across *hypokeimenon* and wondered about it.

- supernal
- dolose
- haecceity
- morological
- accipitrine
- limbus
- *Odobenus rosmarus*

These last six were within two pages. I only knew anything about one of them.

Comment: Is it a new pokemon?

Comment: @stacker:  It's one with *hyper* powers, apparently.

Comment: Was this by chance a book written by Gene Wolfe?

Comment: @Cerberus I think it was a book by L.E. Modesitt, Jr.

Comment: @ErikE: Ah, Modesitt! I read those long ago, but I don't remember in which language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is [Greek in origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_substratum), used by Aristotle to describe "something which can be predicated by other things, but cannot be a predicate of others". To be certain of the *correct* pronunciation, we would have to consult someone who speaks native ancient Greek, which may be difficult.

The best reference that I could find was this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NskAaSocM_c&t=01m23s) of a Greek speaker discussing metaphysics.

The gentleman at [this link](http://www.forvo.com/word/%E1%BD%91%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BD/) (a male from Netherlands) pronounces it something like HAY-PO-KAAAY-MEN-ON, drawing out the AA sound between *hypok* and *menon*.

As a native English speaker, my first instinct is to pronounce it HIGH-PO-KAY-MEN-ON. I would treat the *hypo* prefix as identical in sound to its use in "hypodermic" or "hypoallergenic". I am less certain about the *kei* portion, but KAY sounds more correct than KEE. To my eye, the final *menon* could only be pronounced MEN-ON. Again, this is only my interpretation.

Comment: In other words: [ˌhɑɪ poʊ ˈkeɪ mən ɒn] (where the main stress is on [keɪ], which would also give it the "drawn out" length you describe).

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it didn't occur to me to do searches on the greek word rather than the English one. Also, to my ear, the male from the Netherlenads says "HOO" rather than "HAY", though the OO is inflected in some way I don't know how to describe, almost like a German umlaut U.

Comment: @eja http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NskAaSocM_c&t=01m23s would start the video at 1 minute 23 seconds

Comment: Not "something which can be predicated by other things", but rather "something
of which other things can be predicated".  In non-technical Greek, it just means "what
lies under".

Answer (score 3):

It should be /ˌhɑɪpoʊˈkaɪmənɒn/ “high-poe-KIME-uh-non".

**Explanation:**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypokeimenon), this word is taken from Greek *ὑποκείμενον* (it's actually a letter-by-letter transliteration, aside from the initial “h” which represents the Greek rough breathing mark). The pronunciation of the consonants is unproblematic.

The stress is clearly on the third-to-last syllable, as all the relevant languages involved agree on this (Greek, Latin and English). The prefix “hypo-” already has an [established pronunciation in English](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hypo?q=hypo), which I would advise using (/ˌhaɪpoʊ/, or “HIGH-poe”).

The pronunciation of the last syllable is a bit harder to determine, as the Ancient Greek neuter suffix *-on* is usually converted to the equivalent Latinate suffix *-um* in English words. (For example: *[bacterium](http://bacterium),* from Greek *βακτήριον* *baktērion.* [Cerberus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3607/pronunciation-of-hypokeimenon/257922#comment565671_257922) points out in a comment that the fully Latinized version of "hypokeimenon" would be *hypocimenum.*) However, a good analogy for the vowel sound can be found in the word *[automat**on**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=automaton&ls=a),* from Greek *αὐτόματον automaton.* [Some people](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation/english/automaton) pronounce it as /ən/ “un, while [others](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/automata) pronounce it as ”/ɒn/ “on.”

The second-to-last syllable is unstressed, so will likely simply have a schwa sound in it, /ə/, “uh” or “ih.”

What remains to be determined is the pronunciation of the vowel in the stressed syllable. In general, the digraph “ei” in Greek-derived words, which corresponds to the Greek digraph εἰ, represents a “long i” sound (it is sometimes even interchangeable in the spelling with an “i"). Traditionally, English speakers have pronounced this as the English “long i” sound, /aɪ/, as in the words *[D**ei**mos](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Deimos?s=t),* *[m**ei**osis](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/meiosis?q=meiosis),* *[**ei**dolon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eidolon?s=t),* or *[**i**rony](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/irony?q=irony)* (from Greek *εἰρωνεία eironeia*). Some people might try to use a pronunciation closer to the Modern Greek, and instead use /iː/ (an “ee” sound), but this is not as common a pronunciation for this spelling pattern (although it does occur in some proper nouns, such as [*Cassiop**ei**a*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Cassiopeia&ls=a)).

Although the spelling of the stressed vowel suggests an /eɪ/ “ay” sound to the naive eye, this would be an irregular pronunciation, not in accordance with either the traditional English pronunciation or the modern Greek pronunciation. I would therefore recommend against it. However, there is one argument that could be made for it: it is closest to an early stage of what is believed to have been the [Ancient Greek pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_phonology#Diphthongs) of the *ει* in *ὑποκείμενον*. There is a variety of evidence that the Greek digraph *ει* initially represented a diphthong along the lines of /ei̯/, which later developed in Greek to a monophthong /eː/ (and in Modern Greek /i/). I think someone who used this pronunciation would be more likely to use the spelling *hupokeimenon,* since /u/ is likewise believed to be the earliest vowel quality for the sound represented by the letter *υ* in Greek (early on in most varieties of Greek, it developed to a front rounded vowel /y/ (like German *ü*), which lost its rounding to become Modern Greek /i/). Personally, I don't see any reason to try to approximate the Ancient Greek pronunciation of the diphthong in this particular word, since modern English pronunciation has many other significant and irremediable differences from Ancient Greek (a "proper" Ancient Greek pronunciation would use pitch accent, but English speakers naturally use stress accent, and an Ancient Greek speaker would use an unaspirated /k/, while an English speaker naturally aspirates /k/ at the start of a syllable).

So: the overall pronunciation would be /ˌhɑɪpoʊˈkaɪmənɒn/ “high-poe-KIME-uh-non”, or if you wish, /ˌhɑɪpoʊˈkiːmənɒn/ “high-poe-KEEM-uh-non.”

Comment: Why do you write the /k/ twice in your phonetic transcription? I don't know exactly why, but the /-kaɪmənɒn/ pronunciation seems somehow wrong to me. Possibly something about it only being unstressed ει that yields /aɪ/ in non-proper names? At any rate, I would definitely go with /ˌhaɪpəʊˈkiːmənɒn/ as the safer bet.

Comment: I think it's just an orthographic illusion. Not too many words in English have ei = /aɪ/, so people aren't used to it. But the rules for pronouncing words from Greek are just a bit odd. To me, the pronunciation /kæˈlaɪəpi/ for "Calliope" seems wrong, but it's right nonetheless. I have no idea why a rule like ει =  /aɪ/ only in unstressed syllables of non-proper names would exist, and I don't think it does. Of course, there doesn't have to be a rule. Not all words are pronounced according to rules. But for words like this, that people learn by reading, I think pronunciation rules are useful.

Comment: Here's an example of ει = /aɪ/ in a stressed syllable of a non-proper noun: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108499/how-to-pronounce-deictic

Comment: Wow. Well, I have to admit, that's a new one for me. I've always pronounced the name /ˌkæliˈəʊpiː/. I guess maybe it's just a subconscious rule that I've developed for myself (or, equally likely, the actual rule is something completely different and I misderived it based on the examples I could think of off the top of my head). **Edit:** Good point about _deictic_, that is definitely /aɪ/ for me too.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: Actually, I forgot about vowel weakening. It's really /kəˈlaɪəpi/, but same difference. Regarding "ei," Oxford Learner's Dictionaries annoyingly lists pronunciations for "deixis" and "deictic" with /eɪ/ in addition to /aɪ/. But, I would call these irregular as well.

Comment: The problem is that some recent borrowings or constructions from Greek have violated the rules that have been used for two millennia to translitterate Greek into languages using the Latin alphabet, like this word. It should probably be spelled *hypocimenum*. Cf. the old word *cimeliarch*, also from *keimai*.

Comment: @Cerberus: I agree, and under the regular rules the stressed vowel would be /ɪ/. But there are a fair amount of hybrid or freak words that are unfortunately already well-established, like "hubris," "keratin" and so on. The pronunciation of this word is not established at all as far as I can tell, due to its rarity. There are a variety of ways the word could be transliterated, but I think the pronunciation would vary based on the spelling; my answer is only applicable to the spelling "hypokeimenon."

Comment: @sumelic: Yes, certainly. You had to make do with what you were given. I had already voted your answer up. But I still wished to make this statement. I hereby vow to use *hypocimenum* myself. *Hybris* I already use. *Dixis* I might force myself to use; but *dictic*...I hope I can get used to it. I don't believe we have any old words with *-ei-* from Greek, do we?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone bumps into this question:

- hypokeimenon comes from the greek υ-πο-κεί-με-νο, IPA: i.po.ˈci.me.no. In the context of syntax, υποκείμενο means subject.
- You can listen to a native Greek pronunciation here:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LjmthJ7H5g#t=1m07s
- Google translate's vocalization comes close but puts an emphasis on the second syllable ('πο', υ-πο-κεί-με-νο) which isn't true, as the emphasis should be put on the accent, κει.
  http://translate.google.com/#el|en|%CF%85%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%BF

Comment: English pronunciation is generally closer to Ancient Greek than modern, and not very close to either.

Comment: That video is no longer available, if you have a different resource to offer.